# testng Groups in multiple Suites.xml

Tags: java, testng

Good morning,

when I use a suites.xml globalizer file the include and exclude no longer work

I have the following Suites.xml file:

```
<suite name="allSuites">
     <suite-files>
         <suite-file path="src/exec/testGroups.xml"/>
         <suite-file path="src/exec/testGroups1.xml"/>
         <suite-file path="src/exec/testGroups2.xml"/>
     </suite-files>
</suite>
```

in the following files I have the groups:

```
src/exec/testGroups.xml
   <groups>
     <run>
       <exclude name="systemOperation"/>
       <include name="web_linux"/>
     </run>
   </groups>

src/exec/testGroups1.xml"
   <groups>
     <run>
       <exclude name="systemOperation"/>
     </run>
   </groups>

src/exec/testGroups2.xml:
   <groups>
     <run>
       <include name="systemOperation"/>
       <include name="web_linux"/>
       <exclude name="fictif"/>
     </run>
   </groups>
```

when I execute individually, or in sequence the files

`org.testng.TestNG src/exec/testGroups.xml src/exec/testGroups1.xml src/exec/testGroups2.xml`

includes and excludes work.

when i execute

`org.testng.TestNG /home/eric/git/ats-test/target/suites.xml`

include and exclude no longer work, they are no longer taken into account.